# Editing templates in ui in Azure Devops Services

Tags: azure-pipelines

I like the concept of templates in Azure DevOps. However, one limitation I run into is that it does not allow visualizing the steps of the template in the pipeline editor for a YAML based pipeline. This seems like a big restriction for it's adoption for me personally. Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Editing templates in ui in Azure Devops Services

For this issue , agree with 4c74356b41 , visualizing template step in YAML editor is currently not supported in azure devops.

Currently, only specific tasks can be visualized in the yaml file, by clicking the `settings` above the task. The editor page appears on the right side of the web ui. As for template steps, visualization is not supported for the time being.

[image]

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/920124/visualize-the-template-steps-in-the-yaml-editor-in.html) in DC forum. you could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there,The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it does, thats the whole purpose of YAML templates, they are in code and you can work with those with any text editor.

Comment: I understand. My question is more about visualizing the template steps in the YAML editor in Azure DevOps web portal

Comment: thats what I'm saying, its not possible